# Recommender system using prediction.i.o

Tags: magento-1.9

I have developed an e-commerce website using magento. I want to add recommender systems using Prediction.i.o. Can somebody tell me the steps to do it?

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 4):

Googling "Predictio Magento module" I found: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Predictionio.

So probably just download that and install it.

Comment: have a look on this as well it might me add on https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Implement-Module-for-prediction.io

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar hm too bad they never merged those. Might be something for an upcoming hackathon :)

Comment: I think they have the one you suggested is just for Upsell , mine covers all (related, upsell, crossells ) even i should  post it answer :-p

Answer (score 1):

This extensions attempts to replace the Magento product recommendations ( related, upsell, crossells ) with a new PredictionIO based recommendation engine.

https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Implement-Module-for-prediction.io